# Read Android Logcat messages with Processing

Tags: android, processing, android-logcat

Has anyone had any luck in reading Android LogCat messages with [Processing](http://processing.org)? I have been thinking about making an application in Processing that is controlled by logcat messages triggered by buttons on an Android app, but I need to find a good method of reading and filtering the messages. I have no postable source code yet as I don't want to waste my time building an app that has no way of working. Also, I am not talking about [Android Mode](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Android#Android_Mode) which is used to build .apk files from Processing Code.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide,
Michael

Edit: Just to clarify, The android app will have several buttons, pressing one will produce a logcat message.(think remote control). Processing reads the logcat message and reacts accordingly. I need something that produces something like

```
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) {  
val = myPort.read();
```

But for Android

Comment: Bear in mind that, starting with Android 4.2, the only log messages you can access are ones logged by your process.

Comment: My reading was that this would be a PC application rather than something running on the phone, but perhaps not.  To do this on a PC, an easy suggestion would be to pipe the output of the logcat tool into a processing program which reads its input from stdin (ie, the logcat messages will enter the program almost as if someone were typing them in on the console).   If the goal is to run something on the device, then some form of inter-process communication such as Intents, Binder or unix domain sockets would make more sense than logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Logcat messages could be captured, and then you can process them in Java/Processing and trigger actions based on that. Even without the android mode, you should be able to capture logcat messages via adb.

Although I don't understand why do you want to use processing for this and that too the non-android mode of processing.